# Missing values in Radom Forest and Gradient Boosting

Tags: r, r-caret

I have a dataset with many observations with NA's in one variable (almost a third of them).
My options:

- Try to impute: Due to the caracteristic of the data, I suspect imputation would be inaccurate and should create too much noise
- Remove observation: A third of my dataset? No way!
- Remove variable: It's a very important variable. I think I can get pretty much info from it
- Leave as is. In fact, my variable is not a categorical one, but a numerical one, with a lot of zeroes, My idea is convert them into NA's.

So I'm searching for an algorytm than can handle those NA's, so, instead of having to remove that variable, or loose a lot of observations or introduce noise.

After reading in some dfferent sources, I'm not sure of how theese two family of algorytms algorytms (Random Forest, Gradient Boosting) handle NA's without prblems. My idea was that they can handle them (if, during variable selection, in a tree node, they find an NA, just choose another variable for that node), so I can leave some NA's, that they just omit if necessary, but use th non-NA values of thata variable for trainig the model.

So, with Caret, I have read that I only must set na.action = na.pass, and no preprocessing (do not specify preProcess, leave it as its default value NULL).

Would Random Forest work fine this way? And Ranger? And Gradien boosting?

Comment: This question is really more appropriate for https://stats.stackexchange.com/. To decide how to handle NAs, it can help to think about where they're coming from in your data collection process. In this variable, does an NA mean you took no measurement? If you had made the measurement, there'd presumably be a value, and this is where imputation approaches make sense. If you consider the variable very important, why would you contemplate making all zeroes into NAs? If 0 == NA from your perspective, why not just replace all NA with 0?

Comment: @Seth In this case, my variable is a numeric one with zeroes. But 'zero' is a number that the algorytm consider valid, so I must remove (observation or variable), impute or 'convert' to a value the algorytm can consider 'invalid' and process acordingly.